# jquery document width

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am using to set a div as mask for the entire page.

```
$(document).width();
```

But this behaves differently between IE and Firefox. In IE it gives 796 whereas in firefox it gives 789. 
When i apply the mask's width as  $(document).width();

In firefox the mask is fit to the screen.
But in IE, an extra scroll bar appears below.

I want the mask to fit the screen. Please help me handling this.

window.width() and 100% wouldn't help when i resize the window. I cant use $('body') in place coz, i need to calculate the height in the same manner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literately days of trial and error and searching all the world

Using pureJS because not even jquery reports it properly! but need jquery to identify the browser . I used this to measure body in an iframe- to avoid scrollbars on cross domains communications.. you could tweak it a bit. but the core is there

```
    if ( $.browser.msie ) { 
        var thisH = thisFrame.scrollHeight;     
        var thisW = thisFrame.scrollWidth;      
        }       
    else if ( $.browser.opera )
        {
        var thisW = thisFrame.scrollWidth;
        if (iframe.clientWidth > thisW ) { 
           thisW = 660; //These are custom- you can ignore it
        }

        var thisH = thisFrame.scrollHeight;
        if (iframe.clientHeight > thisH ) { 
            thisH = 550; //These are custom- you can ignore it
              }
        }
    //All other clients
    else                
        {           
        var thisW = thisFrame.scrollWidth;
        if (iframe.clientWidth > thisW ) { 
        thisW = 660; //These are custom- you can ignore it
        }

        var thisH = $(thisFrame).height();
            if (iframe.clientHeight > thisH ) { 
            thisH = 550; //These are custom- you can ignore it
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

> The following code sets the variables winW and winH to the actual
>   width and height of the browser window, and outputs the width and
>   height values. If the user has a very old browser, then winW and winH
>   are set to 630 and 460, respectively.

```
var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}
```